# Insert object into array at specific index in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to add an object at a specific point in my 'data' array which is this components state. The following isn't working, the array simply gets emptied.

```
addNewBulletAfterActive = () => {
    const array = this.state.data;
    const newBulletPoint = {
        id: this.state.data.length += 1,
        title: 'Click to add'
    };
    const newData = array.splice(this.state.activeBulletPointId, 0, newBulletPoint);
    this.setState({
        data: newData
    });
}
```

The idea is that if I have a list of 10 bullet points, the user can click on the 4th bullet point and press enter to add a new bullet point directly after. I've not had any issues adding items to the end of the array but it looks like .splice is causing issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`splice` returns spliced items (which is empty since you splice 0 items) and mutates original array.

```
const newData = array.slice(0); // copy

newData.splice(this.state.activeBulletPointId, 0, newBulletPoint);

this.setState({
    data: newData
});
```

Comment: `splice` will mutate state which is generally a bad practice

Comment: @Valentin I've added slice before splice :)

Comment: So far this is the only answer that actually explains why the OP's code didn't work.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thanks @YuryTarabanko

Answer (score 27):

I believe this should do what you're after.

```
function addAfter(array, index, newItem) {
    return [
        ...array.slice(0, index),
        newItem,
        ...array.slice(index)
    ];
}
```

This function returns a new array with a new item inserted in the middle. It doesn't mutate your original array and so will play nicely with component's state and Redux.

You can then assign the output from this function to your state.

Comment: I think this answer should be the one accepted

Answer (score -1):

I think this could be an easier and faster method to do this

```js
/*Just plain JS*/
function AddAfter(array, newObject){
    array.unshift(newObject);
  }
  
/*In react If updating state*/
var _prev = this.state.your_array; //getting the current value for the state object
var newInfo = {id: 1, more: 'This is a new object'};
_prev.unshift(newInfo);
```