# In REACTJS, same function has different state depending from where (in the dom) is called

Tags: reactjs

Let me start saying that I know that setState is async, this is not the problem I'm having (I guess)!

I have a table and Im storing each row in an array defined as:

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
```

Im rendering the table as:

```
rows.map(r => {
   if(r.prop == 1) {
      return (
         <div key={r.position} onClick={e => AddRow(r.position)}>{r.label} </div>
      )
   }
})
```

The AddRow function just adds a row at the specified index (r.position) shifting and updating all the rows accordingly. Of course Im updating the rows using setRows([...newRows]);

This works perfectly as long as I'm adding a row at the bottom. But if I add a row at position 2 for example and the rows are 10, rows (the array) contains only 2 rows as it did when the second row was added. Same for row 3, row 4.....it's like the AddRow function has been duplicated for each row and uses the state of "rows" at the moment it was duplicated.

I tried removing the if statement but the problem persists. I also tried using a fake id as key but again, the problem is still there.

I have the feeling Im missing something very simple, any idea?

Thanks a lot

For reference, this is the AddRow function

```
const AddTile = (atPosition) => {
        let newPosition = atPosition + 1;

        let newRow = {
            position: newPosition,
            label: 'something',
            prop: 1
        }        

        let tmp = [];
        let counter = 0;
        let added =  false;
        for(let t of rows) {
            if(newPosition == counter) {
                tmp.push(newRow);
                counter++;
                added = true;
            } 
            
            t.position = counter;
            tmp.push(t);
            counter++;
        }

        if(!added) {
            tmp.push(newTile);
        }

        setRows([...tmp]);
  }
```

Comment: Actually, `setState` is **not** `async`, it's a completely synchronous function. It's the React state updates that are asynchronous, i.e. they are enqueued and asynchronously processed. Is `addTile` the same function as `addRow`?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147420/insert-object-into-array-at-specific-index-in-react

Comment: Also if you are inserting something in the Array , we can use the `array index` to keep track of the position . I don't think we explicitly need a `position` property .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

It seems the issue is that you are using the element `position` properties as the react key, so the keys are not stable, meaning that the data doesn't have React keys that "stick" to them so React knows it's the same object from the previous render.

## Solution

I suggest decoupling the "index"/"counter"/"position" from the component as a way of identifying it and using as a React key. Use a GUID that stays with the element and use the mapped `index` as the position for insertion. You should also use a functional state update in `setRows` to update from the previous state versus *some* state that is closed over in callback scope from the render cycle the callback was created. (*Just about any time a state update ***depends*** on any previous state you will want to use a functional update.*)

```
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

...

const addRow = (index) => {
  const newRow = {
    id: uuidV4(),       // <-- new id
    label: 'something',
    prop: 1
  }

  setRows(rows => {
    const newRows = rows.slice();     // <-- copy previous state
    newRows.splice(index, 0, newRow); // <-- insert after index
    return newRows;                   // <-- return new state
  });
}

...

rows.map((r, index) => (
  <div
    key={r.id}                    // <-- use guid as key
    onClick={() => addRow(index)} // <-- use index for insertion
  >
    {r.label}
  </div>
))
```

Also, it seems you may've been trying to do some filtering based on the `prop` value. If so, then do the filter first, *then* map.

```
rows
  .filter(r => r.prop === 1)
  .map((r, index) => (
    <div key={r.id} onClick={() => addRow(index)} >
      {r.label}
    </div>
  ))
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem! I thought this could be the problem and I had tried using a counter as key......just the wrong solution! I added an actual unique id to each element and everything works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry Drew, but I was wrong, only 50% of the problem was in the key The other 50% was with setRows. Passing a function to setRows (to add the new row, as you do in your code) instead of passing the new array already updated (as I did in mine) solved the problem.  I'm guessing that using a function forces REACT to go retrieve the current state or rows.

Comment: @Mark ah, yes, I see... I didn't expressly call it out, but generally when updating arrays in React state you want to use a functional state update so you are updating from the previous state ***and not*** the state from the render cycle the callback was created in. It helps avoid stale enclosures of state. Basically any time the *next* state depends on any *previous* state you want to use a functional update.